# which is the simplest possible google API for hello world?

Tags: java, google-api, cloud, distributed-computing, google-api-java-client

What's the "**simplest**" Google API call to invoke?  Google doesn't *seem* to have a problem with the key, they just want a billing option setup.  Is that strictly required?  I'm not planning on hammering their servers.

Ultimately, looking to run a few mapping queries.  First things first, what Google service or API [would work as a preliminary step towards using](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56510770/262852) the mapping API?

Google translate looks to be a paid service:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldJavaFX$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldJavaFX$ gradle clean run

> Task :run FAILED
Jun 08, 2019 9:35:43 PM net.bounceme.dur.fx.SpikeGoogleTranslate translate
INFO: key               AIzaSyDtE0WRh9l5AIlH6LSKYeeEKioquSWr1UQ
Jun 08, 2019 9:35:43 PM net.bounceme.dur.fx.SpikeGoogleTranslate translate
INFO: from              90210
Jun 08, 2019 9:35:43 PM net.bounceme.dur.fx.SpikeGoogleTranslate translate
INFO: to                90210
Jun 08, 2019 9:35:43 PM net.bounceme.dur.fx.SpikeGoogleTranslate translate
INFO: text              java
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Cloud Translation API has not been used in project 198801459119 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/translate.googleapis.com/overview?project=198801459119 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Cloud Translation API has not been used in project 198801459119 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/translate.googleapis.com/overview?project=198801459119 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:417)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1089)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:515)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:448)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
        at net.bounceme.dur.fx.SpikeGoogleTranslate.translate(SpikeGoogleTranslate.java:45)
        at net.bounceme.dur.fx.App.runApp(App.java:20)
        at net.bounceme.dur.fx.App.main(App.java:14)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldJavaFX$
```

code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.fx;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.translate.Translate;
import com.google.api.services.translate.TranslateRequestInitializer;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SpikeGoogleTranslate {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SpikeGoogleTranslate.class.getName());

    public void translate(Properties properties) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String key = properties.getProperty("api_key");
        String originalLanguage = properties.getProperty("original_language");
        String translatedLanguage = properties.getProperty("translated_language");
        String text = properties.getProperty("text_to_translate");

        log.info("key\t\t" + key);
        log.info("from\t\t" + originalLanguage);
        log.info("to\t\t" + translatedLanguage);
        log.info("text\t\t" + text);

        // set key created via google cloud console
        final TranslateRequestInitializer KEY_INITIALIZER = new TranslateRequestInitializer(key);

        // Set up the HTTP transport and JSON factory
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        // set up translate
        final Translate translate = new Translate.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
                .setApplicationName("My Project")
                .setTranslateRequestInitializer(KEY_INITIALIZER)
                .build();

        // list languages
        {
            System.out.println(translate.languages().list().execute());
            // output: {"languages":[{"language":"af"},{"language":"ar"},{"language":"az"},{"language":"be"},{"language":"bg"},{"language":"bn"},{"language":"bs"},{"language":"ca"},{"language":"ceb"},{"language":"cs"},{"language":"cy"},{"language":"da"},{"language":"de"},{"language":"el"},{"language":"en"},{"language":"eo"},{"language":"es"},{"language":"et"},{"language":"eu"},{"language":"fa"},{"language":"fi"},{"language":"fr"},{"language":"ga"},{"language":"gl"},{"language":"gu"},{"language":"ha"},{"language":"hi"},{"language":"hmn"},{"language":"hr"},{"language":"ht"},{"language":"hu"},{"language":"hy"},{"language":"id"},{"language":"ig"},{"language":"is"},{"language":"it"},{"language":"iw"},{"language":"ja"},{"language":"jw"},{"language":"ka"},{"language":"kk"},{"language":"km"},{"language":"kn"},{"language":"ko"},{"language":"la"},{"language":"lo"},{"language":"lt"},{"language":"lv"},{"language":"mg"},{"language":"mi"},{"language":"mk"},{"language":"ml"},{"language":"mn"},{"language":"mr"},{"language":"ms"},{"language":"mt"},{"language":"my"},{"language":"ne"},{"language":"nl"},{"language":"no"},{"language":"ny"},{"language":"pa"},{"language":"pl"},{"language":"pt"},{"language":"ro"},{"language":"ru"},{"language":"si"},{"language":"sk"},{"language":"sl"},{"language":"so"},{"language":"sq"},{"language":"sr"},{"language":"st"},{"language":"su"},{"language":"sv"},{"language":"sw"},{"language":"ta"},{"language":"te"},{"language":"tg"},{"language":"th"},{"language":"tl"},{"language":"tr"},{"language":"uk"},{"language":"ur"},{"language":"uz"},{"language":"vi"},{"language":"yi"},{"language":"yo"},{"language":"zh"},{"language":"zh-TW"},{"language":"zu"}]}
        }

        // translate
        {
            // phrases
            final ImmutableList<String> phrasesToTranslate = ImmutableList.<String>builder().add("Hello world").add("Where can I walk my dog").build();
            // perform
            System.out.println(translate.translations().list(phrasesToTranslate, "fr").execute());
            // output: {"translations":[{"detectedSourceLanguage":"en","translatedText":"Bonjour le monde"},{"detectedSourceLanguage":"en","translatedText":"Où puis-je promener mon chien"}]}
        }
    }

}
```

The code is from a [gist](https://gist.github.com/prule/75da618b519979b53ebf).

Comment: Did you follow the instructions starting "Cloud Translation API has not been used in project" in the error message? You have to add an API to your cloud project even if it is not a paid-for API.

Comment: I naively selected the translation API without realizing it has no free option.

Comment: I am saying: even if you picked a free API like Fit, you would still have to add that API to your project.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know we used to get this error due 2 reasons.

Either its a new APP created in project and we did not enable it to use. Or, We exceed the daily/total number of hits limit.

You can get full insight over here,

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#403_daily_limit_exceeded

https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/enable-disable-apis